# TextBox max/min numeric value

Tags: winforms, textbox

I have a little problem - in my Windows Forms program I have a lot of text boxes. They only can get numeric values between 1 - 1024. "Protecting" the text box form non numeric inputs is no problem. But how can I assure that the value doesn't get higher than 1024? Is there any function or any event I could try to catch and then Handle it on my own? I thought about catching the "TextChanged" Event and then check for the value. But how can I know then which Button was the last one pressed? 
Besides I wouldn't like to exchange my Textboxes with any other Controls since they're all implemented right now and it would be a lot of work to exchange them all.
Best Regards

Quendras

Comment: Have you checked for non-numeric text being added via Paste - I've seen that one catch out a few 'numeric' textboxes before..

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `NumericUpDown` control and set the `Maximum` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [OnLostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlostfocus.aspx) on each text box.  Then verify the input was numeric, and it's value is greater/equal to 0, and less/equal to 1024.

Answer (score 1):

You could check when that textbox loses focus, and then check its value:

```
public sub Textbox1_lostFocus() handles textbox1.onLostFocus

    If cint(textbox1.text) > 1024 then
     'whatever you need to do here
    End if

end sub
```